# deleting blank columns to create pivot table using excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate the generation of a pivot table for a report I have to write at work. When I import data into excel the data has these extra columns with no information in them. As you probably know, Excel will not create pivot tables when there are extra columsn. Is there a script that can delete the columns that have no data?

A VBA solution is preferable.

[image: image of lossy data with extraneous columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be more efficient than @Siddharth's answer because it only checks the first row.  (But he beat me by many minutes, so +1 to him!)
Since we know that when there is no column heading, Excel will not allow a pivot table to be created.

```
Option Explicit

Sub prepare_for_pivot()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim last_col As Long
    Dim start_row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    start_row = 1
    last_col = ws.Cells(start_row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For col = last_col To 1 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(start_row, col).Value = "" Then
            ws.Columns(col).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Nice one. One comment though ;) In excel 2007/2010 (even though the file is in compatibility mode) you might want to change `256` to `ws.Columns.Count`. Reason being the user has Excel 2007 and he might use the same code for an Excel 2007 file :) The best way is to use .FIND() as mentioned in my post :)

Comment: Sorry one more suggestion :) Change `ws.Cells(start_row, col).Value = ""` to `Len(Trim(ws.Cells(start_row, col).Value)) = 0` because YOURS and MY code will fail if there is a space in the 1st cell.

Comment: quick question: in your code you use the following lines:

`Set wb = ThisWorkbook` <br>
`Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)`

by why isn't this used instead?

`Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`

why do we need two "Set" statements?

Comment: @franklin: you're right. That is good idea to reduce code clutter. I will update answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="*", _
              After:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), _
              Lookat:=xlPart, _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
              MatchCase:=False).Column

    For i = LastCol To 1 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i)) = 0 Then _
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i).Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

I would recommend Adam's way (It is more efficient) for preparing the data for Pivot as per your requirements. My code will fail if there is a blank cell which has a space. You might want to use

`Len(Trim(ws.Cells(start_row, col).Value)) = 0`

in lieu of

`ws.Cells(start_row, col).Value = ""`

in Adam's code.

If you are sure that there will be no blank space then you can use my code as well :)

Sid

Comment: just wanted to let you know that i am accepting @Bernier as per your suggestion. thanks for the quick response and the humility too. man alive. i really appreciate it. and i bet the rest of SO does too.

Comment: No Worries :) For me it has never been about points ;) It's all about the right solution and Adam's solution is better than mine :)